# How to pass the File location as function parameter for a clickable Listview of MediaPlayer files

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I am currently working on an Android app that contains a Listview and records Audio through the MediaPlayer. The recording works fine and I also get a Listview of the recorded MediaPlayer files, which are not yet playable by clicking on the listview entry - that should be the goal.

In specific, I don´t know how to pass the location of the audio file as a parameter to the MediaPlayer object. How should that be done in this case?

I used "file", where the path to the MediaPlayer object is stored, as a parameter but thad doesn´t work.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    static final int  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private ListView mListView;
    private List<String> fileNameList;
    private FlAdapter mAdapter;
    private File file;
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        init_phone_music_list();

        mTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        fileNameList = getFileListfromSDCard();
        mAdapter = new FlAdapter(this, R.layout.fl_list_item, fileNameList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if(mp!=null) {
                    try{
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Log.w("Exception", e);
                    }
                }
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListActivity.this, file);
                try{
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.w("Exception", e);
                }
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }


    private List<String> getFileListfromSDCard() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        List<String> flLst = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) && file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] fileArr = file.listFiles();
            int length = fileArr.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                File f = fileArr[i];
                flLst.add(f.getName());
            }
        }

        return flLst;
    }



    public class FlAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private List<String> fLst;
        private Context adapContext;

        public FlAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                         List<String> fLst) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, fLst);
            this.fLst = fLst;
            adapContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = convertView;
            FHolder fHolder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = View.inflate(adapContext, R.layout.fl_list_item, null);

                fHolder = new FHolder();
                fHolder.fNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fname);
                view.setTag(fHolder);
            }

            else {
                fHolder = (FHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            String fileName = fLst.get(position);
            fHolder.fNameView.setText(fileName);
            return view;
        }
    }

    static class FHolder {
        public TextView fNameView;
    }
    private void init_phone_music_list() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

// Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
// this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
// sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {

// No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

// MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
// app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
// result of the request.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I expect the code to work, but the actual error message is:"cannot resolve method 'create ... java.io.file'.
Any hints or help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to save more information than just the file name in your `fileNameList`. If you change it to a `List<File>` instead, inside the `OnItemClickListener`, you could do `MediaPlayer.create(..., Uri.fromFile(fileNameList.get(position)))`. You're already using a custom `Adapter`, so it would be trivial to change that to `ArrayAdapter<File>`, and modify `getView()` to use `fLst.get(position).getName()`. Also, just FYI, direct file access is being severely restricted in the newest versions of Android, so be prepared to have to change your whole approach, if you need to support those versions.

Comment: @MikeM.: Ok, thanks so far - I wasn´t able to correct that in the code. Could you maybe add the whole Code Snippet? I tried what you´ve recommended but ran into other problems /:

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed your message earlier. Anyway, here are the changes I mean: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ibGoPCeVXmdUuOacoLCOwD94wxOWFm3/view?usp=drivesdk. Just a couple of lines, the `getFileListfromSDCard()` method, and your `Adapter`, which I cleaned up a little.

Comment: @MikeM.: thank you so much for taking the time to put this in a separate file and do a code review :) Thanks a lot! However, as I am not too familiar with Android as it looks, I still get an issue in this line:  mp = MediaPlayer.create(ListActivity.this, Uri.fromFile(fileNameList.get(position))); the error message says: "cannot find symbol variable Uri". I tried to solve this error by putting  Uri uri =   Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)); before that, but that didn´t solved the problem /:

Comment: Oh, you just need to import the `Uri` class: `import android.net.Uri;`. There's a shortcut that'll do it automagically; ctrl+alt+o, I think.